# What's the difference between はずがない, わけがない, and しょうがない?

Tags: word-choice, formal-nouns

A slight expansion of the existing thread [What is the difference between 「はずがない」 and 「わけがない」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/171/what-is-the-difference-between-hazu-and-wake), but what is the difference or use cases for when to use はずがない, わけがない, しょうがない?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On はず and わけ, answers in the original question explain it better than I would so I'll leave it to them.

But on しょうがない, it's totally different from the other two. しょうがない is used when you don't have other choice but to do it. It can also mean "there's nothing else you can do"

p/s: thanks for expanding my question

Answer (score 2):

One differnt with しょうがない　than others is

- You can use しょうがない alone, which means "there is no way", but はず、and わけ need a phrase before those.

Answer (score 1):

しようがない means "there's nothing you can do about it", which is completely different from the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the other thread for hazu vs. wake.

～ようがない　"cannot do ~ because I don't have the means/method to do so".

行きようがない： "I can't go", but maybe because I don't have a vehicle, can't get a ride, etc., not because I wasn't invited, etc.